# I want to build my own operating system ， but how install i686-elf-gcc in manjaro

Tags: gcc, archlinux, manjaro

I want to build my own operating system ， but how  install  i686-elf-gcc in manjaro

i I found a tool（https://github.com/lordmilko/i686-elf-tools）, but it can only be run in ubuntu

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to build the compiler yourself. I went through the same thing recently. If you are into operating system development, you won't be able to avoid looking at the compiler in more detail and [building cross compilation tools](https://wiki.osdev.org/Why_do_I_need_a_Cross_Compiler%3F) anyway.

### Building your own compiler

The build process can be roughly divided into 4 steps:

1. Install all dependencies necessary for the build. If I remember correctly, you can get everything from the official package sources in Arch Linux. Make sure that these packages/tools are present: *make, bison, flex, gmp, mpc, mpfr, texinfo, libisoburn, mtools*.
2. Download the source code of [*binutils*](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/) (GNU's assembler and binary tools) and [*gcc*](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/) (the GNU compiler collection). I recommend using the newest versions at the bottom of the respective pages.
3. Decide where your new compiler should be installed. Although it sounds tempting, it should not end up in any system directory, rather somewhere in your home folder. I used `$HOME/tools/crc` to store my cross-compilation tools. You can at it to your `$PATH` lateron for convenience.
4. Do the actual build. First of all: The build takes a while and needs one or the other command line switch. Do not omit any of them. The build may pass and problems may occur later. Just follow the instructions below.

#### The actual build process

The first thing to do is to compile binutils, because it is needed for the gcc build. For convenience set a few shell variables to minimize error sources:

```bash
# This is where the tools will end up
export PREFIX="$HOME/tools/crc"

# Prefix of the produced assemblies (for example i686-elf-gcc)
export TARGET=i686-elf

# Add the new installation to the PATH variable temporarily
# since it is required for the gcc build
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"
```

Now create a new directory somewhere and extract both the gcc and binutils source code archives in there. You should end up with two subdirectories like `yourdir/binutils-x.y.z` and `yourdir/gcc-x.y.z`. It is recommended to do the build in an empty directory, so create `yourdir/build-binutils` and `yourdir/build-gcc` as well. Notice: These directories are **not** placed inside the source directories!

##### Building binutils

`cd` into the `yourdir/build-binutils` directory and run the following commands. Replace the `x.y.z` part with your version.

```bash
../binutils-x.y.z/configure \
  --target=$TARGET \
  --prefix="$PREFIX" \
  --with-sysroot \
  --disable-nls \
  --disable-werror

make
make install
```

Now check the installation with `which -- $TARGET-as`. This will return the location of `i686-elf-as`, which is the assembler we just build.

##### Building gcc

`cd` into the `yourdir/build-gcc` directory. The process is pretty much the same as with *binutils* above:

```bash
../gcc-x.y.z/configure \
  --target=$TARGET \
  --prefix="$PREFIX" \
  --disable-nls \
  --enable-languages=c,c++ \
  --without-headers

make all-gcc
make all-target-libgcc
make install-gcc
make install-target-libgcc
```

##### Verify the build

Check the installation by invoking `i686-elf-gcc --version`. If you used the same values as I, this can be done with `$HOME/tools/crc/bin/$TARGET-gcc --version`.